# how to fix "500 - Internal server error." while sending newsletter in PHP

Tags: php, newsletter

I am trying to make a newsletter in PHP.
I have datebase in which there are more then 3000 email entries.

When i execute the code on server its shows a server error like:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once "../connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newsletter");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
$mail_body = '';
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row["id"];
$email = $row["email"];
$name = $row["name"]; 

$mail_body = '.... SOME HMTL CODE.....';

$subject = "Anything & Everything Magazine Newsletter";
$headers  = "From:hello@cykotech.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$to = "$email";

$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);

if ($mail_result) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE newsletter SET received='1' WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
}

}
?>
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: A 500 error code on the client is meaningless without the corresponding specific error on the server side. Your code does not contain enough for anyone to assist you otherwise. Please check your logs for an error.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the start of the code to see the errors. Or check logs for an error.

Comment: i put this error code on the start of the code, but nothing happened.. same error... 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. @TuomasK

Comment: now getting error: Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 @TuomasK

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in blast_script.php on line 279